# Auto Update specified tab in Google spreadsheet from Web via script

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am currently trying to pull in data from a website into my Google Sheet, however, it will automatically pull the data on whatever tab I am on when the sheet updates.

The script I currently have is below. I have 5 tabs in the workbook and the tab I need updated is labeled 'Update' and is the 3rd tab in the workbook.

The data currently pulls in correctly, however, it will not only update the tab I need updated.

```
function getData() {
    var queryString = Math.random();
    var cellFunction = '=IMPORTHTML("http://www.golfchannel.com/tours/pga-tour/2017/us-open/?' + queryString + '","table",2)';

    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').setValue(cellFunction);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code line to this:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('Update').getRange('A1').setValue(cellFunction);
```

You can set the sheet by calling the method [**`getSheetByName()`**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String)).

> Returns a sheet with the given name. If multiple sheets have the same name, the leftmost one is returned. Returns null if there is no sheet with the given name.

Here is a sample snippet:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('FILEID'); // sss = source spreadsheet
  var ss1 = sss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 
  var ss2 = sss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');

  var source_range = ss1.getRange("A1:G10");
  var target_range = ss2.getRange("A1:G1");

  source_range.copyTo(target_range);

}
```

Hope this helps.